# How do I implement codeigniter with orientdb?

Tags: codeigniter, orientdb

How do I implement and configure codeigniter with orientdb?. Ofcourse with step by step instructions. Such as how to set the database configuration file, querying, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't find anything that will work out of the box. You might want to take a look at how it's been implemented for MongoDB : https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: I was find orientdb-PHP but still confuse to implement it. Some help?